# No AWS RDS Simple Monthly Calculator for Postgres engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, calculator, amazon-rds, serverless

I have noticed that the AWS SIMPLE MONTHLY CALCULATOR does not have an option to calculate expense for Postgres engine. It offers 'MySQL compatible' as the only option. Am I missing something?

[screenshot of monthly calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGiL5.png)

Comment: Amazon RDS pricing can be found at: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've selected Aurora pricing. Aurora pricing is the same for MySQL and PostgreSQL compatibility. The only difference is that there are some options that are only available in MySQL.